# Difference between RACAble(), RACObserve() and RACBind() in Reactive Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa

I'm new to Reactive Programming. I have gone through the documentation of Reactive Cocoa but couldn't realize the differences between `RACAble()`, `RACObserve()` and `RACBind()`.

Please, help ,me in understanding the aspects by some example code snippets.

I think the `RACAble()` is replaced with `RACObserve()` with some options/arguments. If I am not correct then please correct me in this regard.

Is `RACObserve() skip:` similar to `RACAble()`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I think one big source of confusion here is that 3 months ago the `ReactiveCocoa` team released `v2.0`, which had quite a few breaking changes. This was a great release - and has some amazing features, but it does mean that much of the information you will find on the web is now out-dated.

To your specific points:

1. [RACAble has been replaced with RACObserve](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#simplified-and-safer-kvo)
2. [RACBind has been replaced with RACChannelTo](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/fd533d07b64d40cf79d069584d8cd95158998095/CHANGELOG.md#simpler-two-way-bindings)

`RACObserve` is used to create a signal from an object and a keypath, in other words it allows you to take regular properties and 'lift' them into the ReactiveCocoa world. It is a handy replacement for KVO.

`RACChannelTo` provides a mechanism for two-way binding. In other words you can keep two properties synchronised. A good example of this is if you want to have a property in your view controller, or some model class, bound to a property on a UIKit control.

Another macro you will probably come across is `RAC`, this provides one-way binding. In other words it will set the value of the given property based on the latest value from a signal.

Comment: Thanks a ton for writing this up! I was about to ask a similar question.